# Where to ask about Tendermint connection refused error?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I am having trouble setting up a BigchainDB network and made [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75049535/tendermint-error-bigchaindb-network-connection-refused) about it. However, I'm not sure if that was the correct place to post it. I checked the Stack Exchange sites, however, I'm not sure which one is relevant for this particular problem and therefore I am searching for a recommendation.

> I'm trying to set-up a local BigchainDB network with 3 Raspberry Pis using [this repository](https://github.com/bigchaindb/bigchaindb-node-ansible) as a reference. However, all my nodes encounter a "connection refused" problem on `tendermint.service`. Tendermint is on v0.31.5 and BigchainDB on v2.0.0. I checked if the port is blocked but it seems to be fine.
>
> The error that I am getting is:
>
> `Jan 09 14:52:41 ubuntu tendermint[807]: E[2023-01-09|14:52:41.985] abci.socketClient failed to connect to tcp://0.0.0.0:26658.  Retrying... module=abci-client connnt failed to connect to tcp://0.0.0.0:26658.  Retrying... module=abci-client connection=query err="dial tcp 0.0.0.0:26658: connect: connection refused">`
>
> I am running Tendermint using a unit file:
>
> ```
> [Unit]
> Description=Tendermint. Byzantine-fault tolerant state machine replication.
> Documentation=https://tendermint.readthedocs.io/en/master/
> [Service]
> ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/tendermint node \
>                    --p2p.laddr "tcp://0.0.0.0:26656" \
>                    --proxy_app="tcp://0.0.0.0:26658" \
>                    --consensus.create_empty_blocks=false \
>                    --p2p.pex=false
> WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu
> User=tendermint
> Group=bigchaindb
>
> [Install]
> WantedBy=multi-user.target
> ```
>
> I've also configured the `genesis.json` file in every node:
>
> ```json
> {
>  "genesis_time": "2022-12-19T11:03:38.312591884Z",
>  "chain_id": "test-chain-sveGDu",
>  "consensus_params": {
>      "block": {
>        "max_bytes": "22020096",
>        "max_gas": "-1",
>        "time_iota_ms": "1000"
>       },
>       "evidence": {
>        "max_age": "100000"
>       },
>       "validator": {
>        "pub_key_types": [
>         "ed25519"
>        ]
>       }
>      },
>      "validators": [
>       {
>        "address": "87498C9693362176BFC2A4122133568297865193",
>        "pub_key": {
>         "type": "tendermint/PubKeyEd25519",
>         "value": "dIy8HUovVJatppDrmJieSGW26jWSJrNhzwHMJetysqA="
>        },
>        "power": "10",
>        "name": ""
>       },
>       {
>        "address": "B59216978AB15F31171E8AB482F62D768721DA13",
>        "pub_key": {
>         "type": "tendermint/PubKeyEd25519",
>         "value": "64BTBlnCPSe26HJfpnCkV8A6BS5w//rAqVu/C01sOqA="
>        },
>        "power": "10",
>        "name": ""
>       },
>       {
>        "address": "6067D6D53CD82EBF9C1F4704AC9F27BAE7CB8F9F",
>        "pub_key": {
>         "type": "tendermint/PubKeyEd25519",
>         "value": "QGNyJpLgqjlRanNgtRdAsLTnpylmSo9FymkPFXSnZbI="
>        },
>        "power": "10",
>        "name": ""
>       }
>      ],
>      "app_hash": ""
> }
> ```

Comment: As with the rest of the Stack Exchange network, we prefer that all required info to answer a question be in the post itself rather than behind a link. As such, it would be nice if you edited in a copy of your question (enclosed in blockquote markup) here.

Comment: I edited in a copy of my question here as well, thank you for the guidance.